# Font of siunitx in captions not transfered by options of the caption package

Tags: captions, siunitx

The package option defines the caption text as italic, but this is not reproduced by measures inserted using the \SI functions are not. What can I do ?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,stretch=1.2},format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=it,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{This picture is \SI{8.5}{\cm} long.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}` so the the font options in the locality are detected.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,stretch=1.2},format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=it,format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
   \includegraphics[width=8.5cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{This picture is \SI{8.5}{\cm} long.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]